# Unknown Modifier - preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex, modifier

```
<?php
$url="example.com";
$get=addslashes(file_get_contents($adres)); 
$filter = "#/<\b\>(.*?)<\/b>/#i";
preg_match_all($get, $filter, $result); 
echo $result[0][0];
?>
```

While trying to work with these codes i get  such an error like: "Unknown modifier '<'"

I read other answers about this problem. i know that the problem is about delimiters but what is the solution? Thanks for your helps from now on..

Comment: `preg_match_all (string $pattern, string $subject...)`; are you sure you got it right?

Comment: if not how should modify it? 

    preg_match_all($get, $filter, $result);

This is what i have now...

Comment: preg_match_all pattern must come first then the string  

preg_match_all(pattern, string, match)

preg_match_all($filter,$get,$result);

Comment: preg_match_all($filter,$get,$result);
yes i got the sution with that order..  thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have incorrect order or arguments.Change :

```
 preg_match_all($get, $filter, $result);
```

To :

```
 preg_match_all($filter, $get, $result);
```

Comment: oh my GOD that's it +1.

Comment: same result... :( i still get unknown modifier error

Comment: @user3412957 : `preg_match_all($filter, $get, $result); ` – arguments in the `preg_match_all` function in your code have incorrect order.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that the filter you are looking for is `#<b>(.*?)</b>#i` and not what you currently are using

Comment: yes you are right i changed that one too :) but now i have problem to use the same filter with <p> tags like these  "#<p>(.*?)</p>#i"
 i get the error : unkknown modifier '?'
 could you please help me about that?